# Browser Back button redirect to 1st page while it should go to previous visited page while using Paging

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have search menu option to search cities for meal when i enter city name and clicked on search button meal list are shown to me with 1,2,3,next option of pagination.

But suppose i'm on page 2 and clicked on page 3 and open a Host for meal and if i clicked browser back button or backspace my page will redirect to 1 page of search page while it should go to 3rd page.

And i'm using core PHP, not using any kind of framework.

***Actual Behavior :***

- If am clicking on third page in pune and going to meal_listing page then when
  going back it by default goes to first page.
  Expected Behavior :
- If am clicking on third page in pune and going to meal_listing page then it
  should go to third page.

Comment: is it a `GET` or `POST` request?

Comment: Please share some code with us of the pagination.